# USDT Transaction Dropped & Replaced

Tags: transactions, ethereum, pending-transition

While trying to send USDT to a wallet address, my transaction got dropped and replaced. I assumed that the transaction would go through if I just wait, but it seems that it got replaced and sent to a `0x00000000eddb52AAA642C5ce030A0405f4Db2A87`. This is the current hash: `0x15f15543943ec528af103587f7774812d751d0dafbc514852ade6c3b1e45a4e7` or https://etherscan.io/tx/0x15f15543943ec528af103587f7774812d751d0dafbc514852ade6c3b1e45a4e7.

This is the replaced hash: `0x15f15543943ec528af103587f7774812d751d0dafbc514852ade6c3b1e45a4e7` or https://etherscan.io/tx/0x15f15543943ec528af103587f7774812d751d0dafbc514852ade6c3b1e45a4e7.

If anyone could help me, that would be much appreciate because I really don't want to lose my funds. Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow is to ask quesetions about programming. For Ethereum related questions try https://ethereum.stackexchange.com

Comment: It sounds like your private key or wallet was leaked. Anyway, you can replace that transaction by sending transaction with the same nonce and higher miner fee.

Comment: But the transaction seems to have already been replaced by itself.